# Integrating Oracle OSB 11g with Azure Service Bus Queue

Tags: azure, osb

I have a requirement in which we need to integrate Oracle OSB with Azure Service Bus Queue.

I have used JAVA code mentioned in the below link with set of libraries in classpath for sending the message to the Azure Service Bus Queue Successfully:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues

But While I trying to integrate with OSB using JAVA callout, I am unable to do the same due to dependent Jar file.

I have tried multiple approach by creating a JAR file added library in manifest file.
Buy setting a JAR file in osb domain classpath.

But still while deploying and the code I am facing multiple class not found exception and few are mentioned below:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/codehaus/jackson/JsonFactory
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/codehaus/jackson/JsonGenerator
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/codehaus/jackson/JsonGenerator$Feature
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode

Requesting you to provide any approach to achieve the same.

Comment: Well if all else fails, you can use an @webservice EJB hosted on WLS as a business service.

Comment: can you use maven or gradle that can help you with the dependencies?